# save the result of a function into the global environment

Tags: r, environment-variables

Just a general question...
i create a function that reads a file and store the result into a predefined name, inside the function. Then the function store the result with the function `assign()` into the global environment, with the predefined name. Of course i could do it via executing the function and store the result into a selfnamed Variable (without using `assign()`. It works great for me, but i came to a post in stackoverflow (can´t find it annymore) where somebody gives the advise to never,ever do that. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Because it goes against principles of good functional programming.

The whole reason to use functions instead of simply using one-time scripts is to avoid repetitions and make the code more efficient.

By hard-coding the assignment of the result into the function you actually took away all the benefits of a function while adding the complexity of writing a function.

If there is the need to use the function multiple times, there is also a need to switch up the naming of the result! If you are simply saving an intermediary result, then a) there is no need to do that in global env and b) you are chaining together functions instead of writing one relevant function (which may include other functions to be sure, modularity is key here).

Comment: Thank a lot for this inside Fnguyen